# PHP Validation for form - pregmatch

Tags: php, validation

I set up a class called Validator that validates the input users put into the form.  It is basic right now where it is checking to make sure nothing is left blank, min length and max length.  I am trying to figure out how to check and not allow special characters but have been unsuccessful.  I have tried adding pregmatch but I am implementing it incorrectly or I I just can't implement it by how I set up my code?  Some feedback would be helpful and thank you in advance.

This it the code from my validator file

```
<?php


class Validator
{
    protected $errorHandler;

      protected $rules = ['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength' ]; //special is new -'special'

      public $messages = [
          'required' => 'The :field field is required',
          'minlength' => 'The :field field must be a minimum of :satisfier length',
          'maxlength' => 'The :field field must be a maximum of :satisfier length',
          // 'special' => 'The :field field cannot contain special characters or spaces', 
      ];

    public function __construct(ErrorHandler $errorHandler) // before contstruct there are (2) __ not one _
    {
        $this->errorHandler = $errorHandler;
    }

    public function check($items, $rules)
    {
        foreach($items as $item => $value)
        {

            if(in_array($item, array_keys($rules)))
            {
                $this->validate([
                    'field' => $item,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'rules' => $rules[$item]

                ]);

            }

        }

         return  $this;
    }

    public function fails()
    {
        return $this->errorHandler->hasErrors();
    }


    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errorHandler;
    }



    protected function validate($item)
    {
        $field = $item['field'];

        foreach($item['rules'] as $rule => $satisfier)
        {
            if(in_array($rule, $this->rules))
            {


            if(!call_user_func_array([$this, $rule], [$field, $item['value'], $satisfier]))
                {

                    $this->errorHandler->addError(
                        str_replace([':field', ':satisfier'], [$field, $satisfier], $this->messages[$rule]), 
                        $field);

                    }
                }
            }
        }


protected function required($field, $value, $satisfier)
    {
        return !empty(trim($value));
    }
    protected function minlength($field, $value, $satisfier)
    {
        return mb_strlen($value) >= $satisfier;
    }
    protected function maxlength($field, $value, $satisfier)
    {
        return mb_strlen($value) <= $satisfier;
    }
    //new special
/*
protected function special($field, $value, $satisfier){
        return preg_match(firstname)<=$satisfier;
    }
*/


}


This is the code from my form php file

<?php


require_once 'Class/ErrorHandler.php';  
require_once 'Class/Validator.php';
require_once 'insert_data.php';

$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $validator = new Validator($errorHandler);

    $validation = $validator->check($_POST, [
    'firstname' => [
            'required' => true,
            'maxlength' => 25,
            'minlength' => 3,
            'special'=> preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/','firstname')//new

        ],
        'lastname' => [
            'required' => true,
            'maxlength' => 25,
            'minlength' => 2,
            'special'=> preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/','lastname')//new


        ],
        'password' => [
            'required' => true,
            'maxlength' => 25,
            'minlength' => 7,
            //'special'=> preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/','password')//new


        ]
    ]);


     if($validation->fails())
     {
        echo '<pre>', print_r($validation->errors()->all()),'</pre>';
     }
     else
     {
         insert_request($_POST);
     }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

//pass just regexp in the array, not preg_match that always true there

```
'special' => '/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/' 

protected function special($field, $value, $satisfier){
        return preg_match($satisfier, $value);
}
```